# How can I detect one or combination of strokes of keys in C?

Tags: c, c89

How can I detect one or combination of strokes of keys in ANSI C and/or with Win32 SDK?

For example: how can I detect CTRL+ALT+DEL was pressed?

Please provide me with some source code or any web-link.

Please note that, I am using polling mechanism, not event.

I need to do it in win32 console mode.

Comment: You may not be able to detect CTRL+ALT+DEL from a user space application.  It is detected and acted upon by a kernel mode driver.  You would have to write a kernel mode driver to intercept that combination.  Most other key combinations should be detectable in user space by the method given in Eli's answer.

Comment: @Amardeep: I'm not sure that Autohotkey can't intercept CTRL+ALT+DEL. If it can, then it's surely easier than writing a kernel-mode driver

Comment: @Eli - Are you sure it doesn't install or alter a kmd?  Windows login security would be compromised if ctrl-alt-del could be intercepted by a user space application without admin rights.  I think it may be possible to detect the key combination but probably not before the kmd already acted on it.

Comment: @Amardeep: as I said, I'm not sure about this. If I had such a need I'd check to see what AHK does about it, though

Comment: You cannot without some operating system specific library.

Comment: @EliBendersky: Intercepting Ctrl+Alt+Del would be a very serious security compromise, in NT it is intended to be a Secure Attention Key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete#Windows_NT_family

Answer (score 1):

With ANSI C it is impossible, since ANSI C doesn't define any method to access the keyboard in this manner. The lowest-level function in it that takes input from the user is `getc` that returns a character after it has been entered into `stdin` and ENTER has been pressed.

As for the Win32 API, indeed this can be done. In the message handling function (`WndProc`)you should watch for `WM_CHAR` messages. Modifiers will help you see if CTRL and SHIFT are pressed.

---

P.S. just a thought, maybe what you're looking for is a tool like [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Comment: I need to work with main() not WinMain(). Can you please provide me with any solution?